# Echarts - Can't able align the title to center

Tags: echarts

I am trying the center the title of the echarts component by setting

```
title:{
    text: "My Title",
    textStyle:{
        align: "center"
    }
}
```

But it is not working.

I have referred the official [document](https://echarts.apache.org/option.html#title.textStyle.align)(https://echarts.apache.org/option.html#title.textStyle.align) on this.

JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonswartz/y8zs5coq/5/

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That should be `title.left = 'center'` instead of `title.textStyle.align`. Help you updated at http://jsfiddle.net/ovilia/06u9xpj4/ .

`title.textStyle.align` is used to align the text within the position. For example, if you set `title.textStyle.width` and `title.textStyle.align`, they can work together.

Comment: setting left=center is really confusing

Answer (score 8):

**This also works great:**

```
title : {
        text:"foo",
        subtext:"bar",
        x:'center'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to set `title.left` property to `center`:

```
  title: {
    text: 'My Title',
    left: 'center',
  },
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/xguL0vrk/

Also tested with ECharts 5.0.1